# sshing into cygwin machine with emacs multi-term

Tags: emacs, terminal, cygwin

When I log into a cygwin machine using ssh through a `multi-term` buffer, `(term-send-backspace)` bound to the delete key inserts a space rather than acting as backspace. When ssh connects me to the cygwin machine, these characters are printed: `0;` -- does this indicate that a different set of keymappings are required?